# Unable to submit the form using while loop

Tags: java, mysql, database, forms, jsp

This is my Code that retrieves information from database and displays it in Table with an addition button that will used to submit(add to fav) to another new table with that row values and id of the user Below code displaying all records correctly with in table and every row is wrapped inside a form with button so when i click on a Particular row button then Values of that row only should be passed to target page,But for each and every row only the first record values are passing...

```
<%pst = con.prepareStatement("select * from reg_faculty");
        res = pst.executeQuery();
        while(res.next()) {
            String uname = res.getString(1);
            String id = res.getString(2);
            String branch = res.getString(5);
            String subject = res.getString(4);
            %>
            <tr><td align="center"><b><%=uname%></b></td><td align="center"><b><%=branch%></b></td>
            <td align="center"><b><%=subject%></b></td>
            <input type="hidden" name="fac_id" value="<%=id%>">
<input type="hidden" name="std_id" value="<%=ht%>">
            <input type="hidden" name="fac_name" value="<%=uname%>">
            <td align="center"><img src="viewimagef.jsp?id=<%=id%>&type=<%="faculty"%> " alt="" width="100" height="60" /></td>
            <td align="center"><input type="submit"  value="Add"/></td>
            </tr>

            <%
        }
        %>
```

Target page where the selected row values should pass to database but for any row selected the first record values are passing

```
String std_id1=request.getParameter("std_id");
String fac_id2=request.getParameter("fac_id");
String name=request.getParameter("fac_name");
try{
    pst=con.prepareStatement("select * from fav_faculty where std_id=? AND fac_id=?");
    pst.setString(1, std_id1);
    pst.setString(2, fac_id2);
    res=pst.executeQuery();
    boolean exists = false;
    if(res.next()){
        out.println("Faculty Already exist in your List");
        out.println("Faculty: "+fac_id2+"  Student Id: "+std_id1+"  Name:  "+name);
    }else{
        pst=con.prepareStatement("insert into fav_faculty values(?,?)");
        pst.setString(1, std_id1);
        pst.setString(2,fac_id2);
        int j=pst.executeUpdate();
        if(j>0){
            out.println("You successfully added "+name+" to your Faculty List");
        }
    }
}catch (Exception e) {
    out.println("Unable To Add");
}
```

Comment: you haven't changed the `name` attribute of  `html hidden field` on each iteration which is causing this issue !!

Comment: Is there is any way to resolve this issue.... ??

Answer (score 0):

the problem is in the submit buttons you are using, a submit button belongs to the whole form, a working scenario would be changing the value of the submit button to the faculty id but keeping the same name for all the submit buttons.
another and probably a better solution would be adding a checkbox instead of a submit buttons.

```
      <tr><td align="center"><b><%=uname%></b></td><td align="center"><b><%=branch%></b></td>
            <td align="center"><b><%=subject%></b></td>
            <input type="hidden" name="fac_id" value="<%=id%>">
<input type="hidden" name="std_id" value="<%=ht%>">
            <input type="hidden" name="fac_name" value="<%=uname%>">
            <td align="center"><img src="viewimagef.jsp?id=<%=id%>&type=<%="faculty"%> " alt="" width="100" height="60" /></td>
         <td align="center"><input type="ckeckbox"  name="fac_id" value="<%=id%>">
            </tr>
%><%--  end of the while loop  --%>
<input type="submit" value="add all">
```

and in the target page

```
String allSelectedFacultyIds[]= request.getParameterValues("fac_id");
for (int i=0;i<allSelectedFacultyIds.length;i++)
{ 
pst=con.prepareStatement("select * from reg_faculty where id="+allSelectedFacultyIds[i]);
     //now you have the name, id, ... so the rest of your code should apply with minor changes


}
```

Comment: it is storing all the records,I want only the selected record to be stored

Comment: when you loop through allSelectedFacultyIds, what do you get, you get all the IDs added to the table or only the selected ones ? check [this](http://www.devmanuals.com/tutorials/java/jsp/multiplecheckbox.html)  out!

Comment: all even though i selected only 1 faculty